# Cursor not Anti-aliased

Tags: windows-10, anti-aliasing, mouse-cursor

> ***Don't be confused by the cursor that appears when typing texts into a text field. The cursor that is being talked about here is the mouse cursor (or the mouse pointer).***

---

I just got a new laptop (specs below), but it seems that the cursor is not anti-aliased.

It looks even worse, when I apply shadow at the cursor.

But, it looks great and looks like its anti-aliased, when I enable the Pointer Trails.

I also tried other cursors / cursor schemes, but that don't work either.

*I can't take a screenshot, because the screenshot doesn't show the cursor ...*

> Computer Specs:
>
> Type: Laptop
>
> Operating System: Windows 10
>
> Architecture: 64-Bit
>
> Processor: Intel Core i3-6006U
>
> RAM: 4GB DDR4
>
> Graphics Card:     *(Actually, I have two ...)*
>
> > **Integrated** Intel Graphics
> >
> > **Dedicated** NVIDIA GeForce 940MX (2GB VRAM)

[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]

<sub>*  As you can see above, I have enabled Anti-aliasing on the computer's Graphics Card, and set it to the highest level as possible, but it only "anti-alias" the "other graphics" on the screen, but not the cursor.</sub>

---

### UPDATE:

[image: Using ShareX]

<sub>*  Using ShareX to capture the screen, including the mouse cursor (or the mouse pointer) would not work, because it makes the cursor great on the image, but not on my screen.</sub>

Comment: you can use [3rd party tools](https://superuser.com/q/338891/241386). Most of them can take screenshot of a mouse cursor without problem

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc ShareX would do the thing.  It would capture the screen with the cursor on the screen, **BUT** it would also make the cursor appear nice in the picture.  :(

Comment: did you try other apps?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Not yet!  But, I've heard (from a post also on SU), that ShareX would make the cursor great *(only in the picture ...)*  :(